# Compiling Error

Tags: java, string, types, return

The accompanying code is inadequately organized. Rework it with the goal that it has a finer structure and keeps away from excess. To help wipe out excess, change over the code into a strategy named using that acknowledges two parameters: a Scanner for the comfort, and a String for a solitary individual's name, and prints the suitable data about that individual's bills. Your technique could be called twice (once for John and once for Jane) to duplicate the first code's conduct.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numBills1 = spending(console, "John");
    int numBills2 = spending(console, "Jane");
    System.out.println("John needs " + numBills1 + " bills");
    System.out.println("Jane needs " + numBills2 + " bills");
}

public static int spending(Scanner console, String name) {
    System.out.print("How much will " + name + " be spending? ");
    double amount = console.nextDouble()
        System.out.println();
    int numBills = (int) (amount / 20.0);
    if (numBills * 20.0 < amount) {
            numBills++;
        }
    return numBills;
}
```

Error

```
Return types do not match.
expected return type: void
your return type was: int
```

Comment: What's your question? It looks like you just posted a homework problem.

Comment: that the error that i get when i submit my program i was wondering why

Comment: You seem to be missing a semicolon on the `double amount =` line.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is pretty clear. The validator expects your helper method to not return anything (have `void` return type), but your method returns `int`.
The instructions do say that the helper method should do the printing, so just move that code into the `spending` method, change the return type, and you should be fine.